# Submit a document to sharepoint by email

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

From SharePoint experts, I would like to know if following is possible in SharePoint 2010:

Can we send an offline form (word/excel format document) to SharePoint server by email so that it goes in document management system and undergoes an approval workflow. This feature could be used  by users who have only email access and can't access SharePoint portal.

Comment: Yes. It is possible to upload documents to SharePoint by sending it as email attachment. I found the answer in below links. Sharing it for benefit of others.

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13589/how-to-upload-documents-by-sending-an-email

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/add-content-to-sites-by-sending-e-mail-HA010086730.aspx

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/Pages/How-to-Setup-Mail-Enabled-Document-Libraries-in-SharePoint-2010-Part-4.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is a built in feature in SharePoint 2010.  You have to enable it in central administration.  It is not a simple tasks however.  There is a lot of configuration that needs to happen on the server.   The documentation is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx).